# So im trying to make a c program with a menu that adds/subtracts classes from a linked list... why does this not work

Tags: c, linked-list

problem is occuring "current = head;", "error: cannot convert 'course*' to 'main()::node*' in assignment"

example run should look like:
What courses would you like to do?

1. Add Course
2. Drop Course
3. Print Schedule
4. Exit
   3
   You aren't currently taking any courses.

What courses would you like to do?

1. Add Course
2. Drop Course
3. Print Schedule
4. Exit
   1
   What course name would you like to add?
   Intro_to_C
   What course number would you like to add?
   COP3223C
   Added!

What courses would you like to do?

1. Add Course
2. Drop Course
3. Print Schedule
4. Exit
   1
   What course name would you like to add?
   Computer_Science_1
   What course number would you like to add?
   COP3502C
   Added!

What courses would you like to do?

1. Add Course
2. Drop Course
3. Print Schedule
4. Exit
   3
   Course Schedule:
5. COP3223C - Intro_to_C
6. COP3502C - Computer Science_1

What courses would you like to do?

1. Add Course
2. Drop Course
3. Print Schedule
4. Exit
   1
   What course name would you like to add?
   Concepts_in_Computer_Science
   What course number would you like to add?
   COP2500C
   Added!

What courses would you like to do?

1. Add Course
2. Drop Course
3. Print Schedule
4. Exit
   3
   Course Schedule:
5. COP2500C - Concepts_in_Computer_Science
6. COP3223C - Intro_to_C
7. COP3502C - Computer Science_1

What courses would you like to do?

1. Add Course
2. Drop Course
3. Print Schedule
4. Exit
   2
   What course code would you like to drop?
   COP2100C
   This course is not in your schedule.

What courses would you like to do?

1. Add Course
2. Drop Course
3. Print Schedule
4. Exit
   2
   What course code would you like to drop?
   COP3223C
   Course has been removed.

What courses would you like to do?

1. Add Course
2. Drop Course
3. Print Schedule
4. Exit
   3
   Course Schedule:
5. COP2500C - Concepts_in_Computer_Science
6. COP3502C - Computer Science_1

What courses would you like to do?

1. Add Course
2. Drop Course
3. Print Schedule
4. Exit
   4

Done!

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//linked list of structs 


struct course {
    char name[31], number[11];
    struct course *next;
};
//prints the list


void printList(struct course *h) {
    struct course *temp = h;
    int num = 1;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        printf("%d. %s - %s\n", num, temp->number, temp->name);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

int contains(struct course *h, char code[11]) {
    struct course *temp = h;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(temp->number, code)) {
            return 1;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return 0;
}

int Menu() {
    printf("What courses would you like to do?\n1. Add Course\n2. Drop Course\n3. Print Schedule\n4. Exit\n");
    int value;
    scanf("%d", &value);
    return value;
}

int main() {

    struct course *head = NULL;
    struct node *current = NULL;
    int option = -1;
    while (option != 4) {
        option = Menu();
        if (option == 1) {
            //Add new course
            struct course *new_course = (struct course *) malloc(sizeof(struct course));
            printf("What course name would you like to add?\n");
            scanf("%s", new_course->name);
            printf("What course number would ypou like to add?\n");
            scanf("%s", new_course->number);
            new_course->next = NULL;
            if (head == NULL) {
                head = new_course;
            } else if (contains(head, new_course->number) == 1) {
                printf("Course has already been added.\n");
            } else {
                int flag = 0;
                if (strcmp(head->number, new_course->number) > 0) {
                    new_course->next = head;
                    head = new_course;
                    flag = 1;
                }
                current = head;
                while (current->next != NULL && flag == 0) {
                    if (strcmp(current->next->number, new_course->number) > 0) {
                        new_course->next = current->next;
                        current->next = new_course;
                        flag = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                    current = current->next;
                }
                // inserts at the end;
                if (flag == 0) {
                    current->next = new_course;
                }
            }
        } else if (option == 2) {
            //Remove course
            char remove[11];
            int flag = 0;
            printf("What element would you like to delete?\n");
            scanf("%s", remove);
            while (head != NULL && strcmp(head->number, remove) == 0) {
                head = head->next;
                flag = 1;
            }
            current = head;
            while (current != NULL && current->next != NULL) {
                if (strcmp(current->next->number, remove) == 0) {
                    current->next = current->next->next;
                    flag = 1;
                } else {
                    current = current->next;
                }
            }
            if (flag == 0) {
                printf("This course is not on the schedule.\n");
            } else {
                printf("The course has been deleted.");
            }
        } else if (option == 3) {
            //Print out schedule
            printList(head);

        }
        return 0;

    }
```

Comment: "does not work" is never a good problem description. Don't expect people to work out what a dump of unexplained code and output is supposed to mean. What is the exact input, expected result and actual result?  More importantly, what debugging have you done and what did you find? Run your program in a debugger and step thru it to trace the program flow and variable values to find where things first start going wrong.

Comment: ok thank you this is my first post ever.. i will do better.. Anyway the problem is occuring "current = head;", "error: cannot convert 'course*' to 'main()::node*' in assignment" im pretty new to pointers so any input u can offer helps alot.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72022386/edit) your post to add the error message. It should be obvious that you need to show the actual error you are asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `head` is of type `struct course *`, whereas the variable `current` is of type `struct node *`. Since they are of different type, you cannot assign one to the other.

You probably want to make the pointer `current` of type `struct course *` instead. So you should change the line

```
struct node *current = NULL;
```

to:

```
struct course *current = NULL;
```

Comment: Thx you so much GOAT